buildx build --platform linux/amd64 significantly increases image size with poetry
Packages installed by poetry significantly increases the image size when it's built for amd64.
I'm building a docker image on my host machine(MacOS, M2 Pro), which I want to deploy to an EC2 instance. Normal build will make an image size of 2GB, which is good. But it will result in system compatibility issue when deployed on EC2: WARNING: The requested image's platform (linux/arm64/v8) does not match the detected host platform (linux/amd64/v3) and no specific platform was requested. So I am trying a build with buildx command. However, it results in whopping 13GB, even though all I changed was a build command. I'd like to know why and how to reduce the size.
Here is the Dockerfile (Edited: tried multi-stage build based on this answer):
FROM python:3.11-slim as builder

# Set environment variables to make Python and Poetry play nice
ENV POETRY_VERSION=1.7.1 \
    PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 \
    PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1 \

# for -slim version (it breaks if you don't comment out && apt-get clean)
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    gfortran \
    libopenblas-dev \
    liblapack-dev \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

## Install poetry
RUN pip install "poetry==$POETRY_VERSION"

## copy project requirement files here to ensure they will be cached.
WORKDIR /app

COPY pyproject.toml ./

RUN poetry config virtualenvs.create false \
    && poetry install --no-interaction --no-dev --no-ansi  --verbose \
    && poetry cache clear pypi --all

FROM python:3.11-slim

# Copy all of the python files built in the Builder container into this smaller container.
COPY --from=builder /app /app
COPY --from=builder /usr/local/lib/python3.11 /usr/local/lib/python3.11

EXPOSE 7070

CMD ["poetry", "run", "flask", "run", "--host=0.0.0.0"]

And this command will build a 2GB image.
docker build -f ./docker/Dockerfile \
-t malicious-url-prediction-img:v1 .

And this will make a 13GB image
docker buildx build --platform linux/amd64 -f ./docker/Dockerfile \
-t malicious-url-prediction-img:v1-amd64 .

The image size stays small if I remove the RUN command poetry config virtualenvs.create..., even if I build the image for amd64. So I assume that poetry is causing this problem. However, it still is weird to have such a big difference in size by just changing the build context.
Edited: Based on two answers from anthony sottile and Ghorban M. Tavakoly, the cause might be the torch. I changed my pyproject.toml file like this:
[tool.poetry]
name = "malicious-url"
version = "0.1.0"
description = ""
authors = ["Makoto1021 <makoto.miyazaki1021@gmail.com>"]
readme = "README.md"


[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.11"
numpy = "^1.26.4"
tld = "^0.13"
fuzzywuzzy = "^0.18.0"
scikit-learn = "^1.4.1.post1"
pandas = "^2.2.1"
mlflow = {extras = ["pipelines"], version = "^2.11.3"}
xgboost = "^2.0.3"
python-dotenv = "^1.0.1"
imblearn = "^0.0"
flask = "^3.0.3"
torch = {url = "https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu-cxx11-abi/torch-2.2.2%2Bcpu.cxx11.abi-cp311-cp311-linux_x86_64.whl"}
googlesearch-python = "^1.2.3"
whois = "^1.20240129.2"
nltk = "^3.8.1"

[tool.poetry.group.dev.dependencies]
ipykernel = "^6.29.3"
tldextract = "^5.1.2"

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"

This resulted in an image of 10GB. Happy with the progress but still quite big for my EC2 instance. Here's the result of /bin/bash and du -h -d 1.
4.0K    ./mnt
1.9G    ./usr
4.0K    ./opt
4.0K    ./boot
0       ./sys
6.8M    ./var
4.0K    ./media
4.0K    ./tmp
1.4M    ./etc
4.0K    ./home
du: cannot access './proc/12/task/12/fd/7': No such file or directory
du: cannot access './proc/12/task/12/fdinfo/7': No such file or directory
du: cannot access './proc/12/fd/8': No such file or directory
du: cannot access './proc/12/fdinfo/8': No such file or directory
0       ./proc
8.0K    ./run
24K     ./root
0       ./dev
4.0K    ./srv
216K    ./utils
8.1G    ./app
10G     .

FYI, this is how I run the container.
docker run --rm -p 7070:5000 -v $(pwd)/logs:/app/logs malicious-url-prediction-img:v1-amd64

EDITED 1:

changed Dockerfile to minimal example
added myproject.toml to reproduce the build
added my investigation on poetry

EDITED 2:

updated Dockerfile with multi-stage build
updated .toml file and the result


This doesn't solve your problem, but you should not be running flask directly like that. You want to use gunicorn in front of it. The multi-py gunicorn project has a container you can work with for that: https://github.com/multi-py/python-gunicorn. I'll give you a better answer in a second.

it's impossible to tell without a working reproduction of your build -- you've left out many important details which make it so one cannot see what you're seeing.  try and reduce your dockerfile to a minimal example (you may even find the answer while doing this!)

@anthonysottile I followed your advice and updated the OP with a new Dockerfile and added a pyproject.toml, so you can reproduce it. I also narrowed down the cause to poetry. still can't figure out why and how to reduce the size, tho.

please run docker run --rm malicious-url-prediction-img:v1-amd64 du -h -d 1 /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages to find the cause of this big size.

Since you use poetry, you must change /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages with respective dir in your env. It must be in /root/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/

@GhorbanM.Tavakoly I updated my OP with du -h result

Wait, the cause maybe the ml model in app directory..

you must go deeper and deeper in app directory using du to find the cause.

the difference between the arm64 and amd64 image size comes down to a conditional architecture-dependent dependency
torch on amd64 pulls in a series of nvidia* dependencies to support gpu development -- but does not pull those in on other architectures: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/7a6edb0b6644eb2b28650ea3be1c806e4a57e351/.github/workflows/generated-linux-binary-manywheel-main.yml#L51
nvidia-cuda-nvrtc-cu11==11.8.89; platform_system == 'Linux' and platform_machine == 'x86_64' ...

you can see this reflected in the wheel metadata from pypi:
$ curl --silent https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c3/33/d7a6123231bd4d04c7005dde8507235772f3bc4622a25f3a88c016415d49/torch-2.2.2-cp311-cp311-manylinux1_x86_64.whl.metadata | grep platform_system
Requires-Dist: nvidia-cuda-nvrtc-cu12 (==12.1.105) ; platform_system == "Linux" and platform_machine == "x86_64"
Requires-Dist: nvidia-cuda-runtime-cu12 (==12.1.105) ; platform_system == "Linux" and platform_machine == "x86_64"
Requires-Dist: nvidia-cuda-cupti-cu12 (==12.1.105) ; platform_system == "Linux" and platform_machine == "x86_64"
Requires-Dist: nvidia-cudnn-cu12 (==8.9.2.26) ; platform_system == "Linux" and platform_machine == "x86_64"
Requires-Dist: nvidia-cublas-cu12 (==12.1.3.1) ; platform_system == "Linux" and platform_machine == "x86_64"
Requires-Dist: nvidia-cufft-cu12 (==11.0.2.54) ; platform_system == "Linux" and platform_machine == "x86_64"
Requires-Dist: nvidia-curand-cu12 (==10.3.2.106) ; platform_system == "Linux" and platform_machine == "x86_64"
Requires-Dist: nvidia-cusolver-cu12 (==11.4.5.107) ; platform_system == "Linux" and platform_machine == "x86_64"
Requires-Dist: nvidia-cusparse-cu12 (==12.1.0.106) ; platform_system == "Linux" and platform_machine == "x86_64"
Requires-Dist: nvidia-nccl-cu12 (==2.19.3) ; platform_system == "Linux" and platform_machine == "x86_64"
Requires-Dist: nvidia-nvtx-cu12 (==12.1.105) ; platform_system == "Linux" and platform_machine == "x86_64"
Requires-Dist: triton (==2.2.0) ; platform_system == "Linux" and platform_machine == "x86_64" and python_version < "3.12"

and in the aarch64 wheel as well:
$ curl --silent https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/cd/fd/2121f53629c433589273a2e8f71d29705e98024e0abe2360e63b852e80bb/torch-2.2.1-cp311-cp311-manylinux2014_aarch64.whl.metadata | grep platform_system
Requires-Dist: nvidia-cuda-nvrtc-cu12 ==12.1.105 ; platform_system == "Linux" and platform_machine == "x86_64"
Requires-Dist: nvidia-cuda-runtime-cu12 ==12.1.105 ; platform_system == "Linux" and platform_machine == "x86_64"
Requires-Dist: nvidia-cuda-cupti-cu12 ==12.1.105 ; platform_system == "Linux" and platform_machine == "x86_64"
Requires-Dist: nvidia-cudnn-cu12 ==8.9.2.26 ; platform_system == "Linux" and platform_machine == "x86_64"
Requires-Dist: nvidia-cublas-cu12 ==12.1.3.1 ; platform_system == "Linux" and platform_machine == "x86_64"
Requires-Dist: nvidia-cufft-cu12 ==11.0.2.54 ; platform_system == "Linux" and platform_machine == "x86_64"
Requires-Dist: nvidia-curand-cu12 ==10.3.2.106 ; platform_system == "Linux" and platform_machine == "x86_64"
Requires-Dist: nvidia-cusolver-cu12 ==11.4.5.107 ; platform_system == "Linux" and platform_machine == "x86_64"
Requires-Dist: nvidia-cusparse-cu12 ==12.1.0.106 ; platform_system == "Linux" and platform_machine == "x86_64"
Requires-Dist: nvidia-nccl-cu12 ==2.19.3 ; platform_system == "Linux" and platform_machine == "x86_64"
Requires-Dist: nvidia-nvtx-cu12 ==12.1.105 ; platform_system == "Linux" and platform_machine == "x86_64"
Requires-Dist: triton ==2.2.0 ; platform_system == "Linux" and platform_machine == "x86_64" and python_version < "3.12"

these dependencies are not pulled in on arm64 (aarch64):
# du -hs /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/{triton,nvidia}
420M    /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/triton
2.8G    /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/nvidia

(there may be more as well, I only traced torch which I'm familiar with its dependency problem as I couldn't build your docker image since I ran out of disk space!)

Wow. if this is the case, basically there's no way to reduce the image size other than abandoning torch(I'm using it because my model is a neural network)

actually you can avoid cuda and other gpu backends for torch. just use torch-cpu. https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch/

You could also add another command to your dockerfile that explicitly deletes the nvidia and triton packages, just make sure you do it as part of the same step so the files don't get stuck in one of the layers.

I figured out that the ML models which were unintentionally included in the image increased the size of the image. Investigating the /app directory inside the image helped(thanks @GhorbanM.Tavakoly for the advice)
Here is the simplified Dockerfile I initially had:
FROM python:3.11-slim as builder

# Set environment variables to make Python and Poetry play nice
ENV EXPERIMENT_ID=$EXPERIMENT_ID \
    RUN_ID=$RUN_ID

# install system dependencies

## Install poetry

FROM python:3.11-slim

# Copy all of the python files built in the Builder container into this smaller container.
COPY mlartifacts/$EXPERIMENT_ID/$RUN_ID/ /app/mlartifacts/$EXPERIMENT_ID/$RUN_ID/

EXPOSE 7070

CMD ["poetry", "run", "flask", "run", "--host=0.0.0.0"]

The problem was the environment variables EXPERIMENT_ID and RUN_ID. They were declared only under the builder stage, not under the main stage. Therefore, as a result, all files and directories under mlartifacts/ directory were copied to the image, resulting in a large image.

Some ISAs may produce smaller/larger builds. But increase amount in size in your case isn't normal. Here I propose an small refactoring in your Dockerfile.
I use this trick allways, but I didn't test here.
You need gfortran and some other packages to build your python packages. After build, they aren't necessary and you can uninstall them.
RUN apt install -y gfortran liblapack liblapack-dev libopenblas libopenblas-dev
RUN build your packages
RUN apt purge gfortran lapack-dev openblas-dev
RUN apt autoremove --purge
RUN other-cleanups

But above codes does not reduce your docker images, since build dependencies exists in above layers. You must change above code to:
RUN apt install -y gfortran liblapack liblapack-dev libopenblas libopenblas-dev ; \
    build your packages ; \
    apt purge gfortran lapack-dev openblas-dev ; \
    apt autoremove --purge

This will decrease your image size considerably.
apt, pip and ... (apt by default, deletes downloaded .deb files however)downloads files in cache directories. You can add --mount=type=cache to your RUN argument to cache them in seperate cache volumes, not in your images.
So here is your refactored Dockerfile (I add liblapack and libopenblas so they must stay after apt autoremove):
FROM python:3.11-slim

ENV POETRY_VERSION=1.7.1 \
    PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 \
    PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1 \
    EXPERIMENT_ID=$EXPERIMENT_ID \
    RUN_ID=$RUN_ID

WORKDIR /app
COPY poetry.lock pyproject.toml ./

RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/var/cache/apt \
    --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.cache/pip \
    --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.cache/pypoetry/cache \
    set -eux ; \
    apt update && apt install -y gfortran libopenblas libopenblas-dev liblapack liblapack-dev ; \
    pip install "poetry==$POETRY_VERSION" ; \
    poetry install --no-interaction --no-dev --no-ansi  --verbose ; \
    poetry cache clear pypi --all ; \
    apt purge gfortran libopenblas-dev liblapack-dev ; \
    apt autoremove --purge ; \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

COPY mlartifacts/542535033067401306/2ba405d6d3144db6a5cd237509e53ef8 /app/mlartifacts/542535033067401306/2ba405d6d3144db6a5cd237509e53ef8/
COPY data/blacklist.txt data/whitelist.txt /app/data/
COPY *.py .
COPY utils/ ./utils/
COPY .env .

EXPOSE 7070

CMD ["poetry", "run", "flask", "run", "--host=0.0.0.0"]


@ghorban-m-tavakoly thanks for a nice idea. I had to add DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 in the build command, and add DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive and -y after autoremove. But it still resulted in 13GB image...

You can use cpu based torch.
Just add this to the top of your pyproject.toml:
[[tool.poetry.source]]
name = "torch"
url = "https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu"
priority = "primary"

then in your [tool.poetry.dependencies] section, add proper torch version:
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
torch = { version = "^2.2.2", source = "torch" }

my corrent network speed is too slow. so I can't test it. maybe you need to change version of torch to something similar to ^2.2.2+cpu or ... to select proper cpu version of torch.
